# How to use getAssets().open(filename) with FileWriter?

Tags: java, android, filewriter

This is the code I tried:

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES"),append);
```

But it gives this error while compiling:
"The method getAssets() is undefined for the type class1"

What is the correct usage in this scenario?

Comment: Open a file named "USCOUNTIES" which is located in the assets folder.
This is for an android app.

Comment: What type of file is that, is it a txt file , pdf etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to assets. `open()` returns an `InputStream`; you cannot write to an `InputStream` with a `FileWriter` or anything else. This is above and beyond the error you are getting (caused by trying to call `getAssets()` on something that is not a `Context`).

Answer (score 0):

The method `getAssets()` is part of the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29), you could call it on the context itself or its subclass the `Activity`. You should pass the Context where its needed

```
public void doSomethingRelatedToFiles(Context ctx){
    AssetManager am = ctx.getAssets();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The getAssets() method is defined in the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29) interface. So the error you have means that class1 is not implementing Context interface.

Basically, this method is available from Activity and Service and Resource classes.

So you need to pass the Context as method argument. Do something like this :

```
public void myMethod(Context context){
    ...
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(context.getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES"),append);
    ...
}
```

And assuming you are calling `myMethod` from an activity, do something like this:

```
class1Instance.myMethod(this);
```

Comment: You should pass the Context to the method using it just like Ben did, note that 'this' refers to the Activity instance which is a subclass of the 'Context'